# Bash script using find and grep

Tags: linux, bash

I am using bash script to match certain words but it's not working, it should give me color output using grep command.

```
warrior(){
    echo ""
    for i in ${sources[@]}
    do
    echo ""
    echo ""
        a=$(grep -n "\$_${i}" $f | grep -o "\$.*=" | sed "s/[ ]\?=//g" | sort -u)

        for j in ${sinks[@]}
        do
            grep --color -n "${j}.*\$_${i}" $f

            for k in $a
            do
                grep --color -n "${j}.*$k" $f
            done
        done
    done
}

if [ $f != "-r" ]
then
    warrior
else
    for i in $(find $2 -type f -name "*.*")
    do
        echo "File: $i"
        f=$i
        warrior
    done
fi
```

Expected output:

```
14:     document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + username + '!';
36: document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Current market index is ' + market.index + '.';
```

Error output:

```
./myprog.sh test
- empty results
```

Comment: Can you include the command you use to run it, the actual output, and the expected output?

Comment: Spawning 7 subshells per-iteration is going to be horribly s l  o w . . .

Comment: that's the point. I need it this way only

Comment: You don't assign to `sources` or `sinks`, and only assign to `f` after using it for the first time. Also, there are a bunch of variable/array references that should have double-quotes around them, and `for ... in $(find ...)` is not a good way to iterate over files. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting problems like these.

Comment: sources and sinks have java codes, so code would be too lengthy then to post here, I am thinking problem lies at find and grep syntax.

Comment: In the expression `if [ $f != "-r" ]` you have quoted exactly the wrong thing.  There is no possible interpolation in `-r`, so `"-r"` and `-r` are guaranteed to be the same thing.  However, if `$f` if the empty string, then `if [ $f != -r ]` is an error, since `[` does not expect its first argument to be `!=`. IOW, quote your variables, not your fixed strings.  Or quote both: `if [ "$f" != "-r" ]` or `if [ "$f" != -r ]`

Comment: This will be very slow. It's way better to create one long grep argument and run grep on all files once.

Answer (score 0):

All code is ok, error was grep -o and sed commands were extra also \$_ was being interpreted as E-O-L by grep , deleting it, fixed the issue.